# How to make AVPlayer work with AirPlay without mirroring?

Tags: avfoundation, avplayer, airplay, apple-tv

I am trying to get AVPlayer to play on an AppleTV using AirPlay. It seems simple and according to Apple docs it should be supported.

Here's the code:

```
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:_composition];
playerItem.audioMix = _audioMix;
playerItem.videoComposition = _videoComposition;

_currentPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
[_currentPlayer setAllowsExternalPlayback:YES];
[_currentPlayer setUsesExternalPlaybackWhileExternalScreenIsActive:YES];
[_currentPlayer setAllowsAirPlayVideo:YES];
[_currentPlayer setUsesAirPlayVideoWhileAirPlayScreenIsActive:YES];
[_currentPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"rate" options:0 context:nil];
[_currentPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"externalPlaybackActive" options:0 context:nil];
```

One thing I noticed is that the player time doesn't seem to move forward when I turn on AirPlay and sometimes I think it actually jumps back a second or two.

Any ideas?

**Side Notes:**

- The composition is built using AVFoundation and the format for the video is H.264.
- It works if I turn on mirroring and push the view to the second screen
- The sound works if played without the video.

**References:**
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AirPlayGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011045-CH1-SW1

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009530

Comment: It seems like there's a bug with using a AVComposition and AirPlay:

http://openradar.appspot.com/14275139

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, I was going crazy for hours till I found it the answer!

Set this to `NO`

```swift
[_currentPlayer setAllowsExternalPlayback:NO];
```

and remove this line

```swift
[_currentPlayer setUsesExternalPlaybackWhileExternalScreenIsActive:YES];
```

It will work!